# Similar content not ranking for 50 states, but ranking for US territories

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

This is a follow up on a [previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131715/seo-best-practice-for-page-that-is-the-same-for-50-us-states) I asked regarding the best way to set up my website to appropriately show up on Google.

I have a calculator for each US state: let's say you plug in your income and it tells you your state tax rate, which depends on your state.

The calculator has same UI for ever state, one simple form, with a few minor differences. The big difference is the page title and H1 tag "PA Tax Calculator" and "Pennsylvania Tax Rates." Of course, your results depend on the state which is generated using JS -- that is extremely different depending on your state, but likely not something that Google would be able to see.

The calculator works for 50 states + Guam and Virgin Islands. I submitted a `sitemap.txt` file with all 52 states / territories to Google.

**Only my calculators for Guam and Virgin Islands are showing up on Google** -- nothing for New York, Kansas, Delaware etc.

I suspect this is due to Google filters preventing people from using states as keywords when there really is no page difference, and their filter does not apply to the US territories.

Am I correct? And is there a solution?

Comment: "Google filters preventing people from using states as keywords" - ???

Comment: @MrWhite what I mean by that is it seems like for any article, even if it isn't state specific, you could toss a state name in front of it to make it appear more personalized, even if it isn't. E.g. "How to improve your wifi speeds... in Pennsylvania"

Answer (score 1):

You should read this https://www.seroundtable.com/archives/017725.html - if you can create useful and unique content for each page - than it's fine.

And about indexing the rest of pages by Google - there is a bit slowly process now - because of google actually problems with the canonicalization and mobile-indexing issues.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. It seems extremely significant that only the territory pages are being ranked, and only when clicking the "If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included" option